# Unity3D Facebook SDK requires multiple login on Android

Tags: facebook-unity-sdk

I'm having issues with the Unity3D facebook SDK. The integration works fine and I can make FB.API and FB.AppRequests with no trouble. However, I have to login afresh everytime I exit the app and try to make one of these requests.

Shouldn't the user be logged in automatically on FB.init after first login? This is really disrupting the user experience we are trying to create. Can anyone help on this?

I'm using Unity Facebook SDK 5.1, but the same issue was observed on 5.0.4 (I hoped that upgrading would fix this).

Comment: are you calling FB.init()? When you are logged in, your session should be re-created when you call init

Answer (score 1):

Check FB.IsLoggedIn in the callback from FB.Init().

Working for us with SDK 5.0.4 on Android and iOS.
Not in the editor though.